# Netlogo - making a row of turtles stop when the first one comes to a halt

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo, so I apologise if this is a dumb question.

I have a row of turtles representing people walking in single file along a path. Occasionally one of the turtles will pause. I need all the turtles immediately behind the turtle to stop at the same time so they don't pile up on one another. Is there is a simple way of doing this?

So...

ooooo - line of people walking along

xxxxx - first one stops

and

ooooo - another line of people walking along

xxx oo - middle one stops, everyone behind him stops, people in front keep walking

and

ooo  oo - line of people walking along with a gap between them

ooo xx - front of line stops, people behind keep walking

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Mike.

Comment: This is WAY too broad a question. How you do this depends on how you set up your model. But here's a couple of approaches you can think about. (1) If you have one person per patch, use the `patch-ahead` primitive to check if the path is clear before moving. (2) If you have lots of people, have each person store the person ahead as one of the variables they own, and simply check if that person has stopped. Either way, you will also need to think about having your people make the move decisions in order.

Comment: Way too broad indeed. Still, look at the Traffic models in the NetLogo Models Library: they are doing something similar to what you are asking and may serve as inspiration...